# Calculate Precision and Recall by using data in Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate Precision and Recall for a multi class classifier.

I have a Spark DataFrame with 2 columns, GroundTruth and Predicted Class.

To calculate the metrics using precision_score/recall_score API in sklearn,  I need the columns in spark DataFrame as python list.

The way I am doing it is:

```
predicted_class_list = df.select(Predicted_Class).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
gt_list = df.select(Ground_Truth).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

precision_score(gt_list, predicted_class_list, average=None)
```

It takes forever to run  **df.select(Predicted_Class).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()**

At times it takes 3-4 hours for it to run just for 100,000 rows.

Is there a way to Optimize the code so that it takes less time?

Comment: any reason choosing sklearn's `precision_score` over pyspark's `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`?